# Weight paint too sharp transition between affected areas

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, weight-painting

I try to weight paint my mesh, but no matter what settings I put in weight or strength option, there is a super sharp difference between where I painted and clean mesh. Why does this happen? I can't paint a smooth transition no matter what I try. The transition is very sharp even though the weights are almost blue.

[image]

Comment: it might look sharp but it's actually not, select your object, go in Edit mode, open the Viewport N panel > Item > Vertex Weight, select some vertices, you'll see that the weight will be different even though the color seems to be the same.

Comment: Hey! Edit mode also shows a hard transition, but also when I exit pose mode into object mode, the mesh is super deformed....

Comment: Pose mode is for bones, if the mesh is deformed it's because the armature doesn't act the way you want, when you parent the object to its armature, make sure in Pose mode that the bones are in their Rest pose (alt G, alt R, alt S)

Comment: Yes, when the armature is resting, everything is fine. But this hard transition is what causes problems. Since I can't get a smooth transition like in the screenshot, when I change the pose, the mesh gets deformed accordingly to the hard transition.

Comment: if weight painting is not precise enough, go in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, select the vertices you want, and assign them the weight you want, playing with the Weight value under the Vertex Groups list

Comment: I started to paint the weight from scratch, and now it seems the brush does not react to ANY setting at all... I can't change the smoothness of the transition and in edit mode, when I select the vertices that I painted and try to reduce the weight like you said, nothing changes.....
here is a screenshot 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xAU9BdpU-kOG0BbH0xOxQoVdD7P4yeNJ

Comment: does the same thing happen with the same file but an older version of Blender? Just to make sure it's not a bug...

Comment: I guess I have to try it out on older versions

Comment: Also with the same blender version try to append the object in a new file to make sure it's not caused by a brush setting

Answer (score 0):

On another forum I finally got an answer!
The problem was that since I erased all weights from all bones to paint weights from scratch, all vertices other than the painted, had to be attached to any other bones. Basically one vertex needs to be attached to more than one bone.

Comment: mmh sorry I don't understand, maybe try to elaborate... no a vertex doesn't need to be assigned to more than one bone

Comment: So, when I painted vertices on the leg bones and after I moved the leg to check, the whole mesh went crazy because all other vertices were not attached to anything. Only after I attached all the other vertices to other bones, the mesh knew where it was and I could also have smooth transitions between weights